# JUnit test always fails when comparing two objects

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, junit, spring-data-cassandra

I have a Test Class like this,
basically these was copy-paste from spring-data-examples.

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = CassandraConfig.class)
public class UserRepositoryTest {


    @Autowired UserRepository repository;
    @Autowired Session session;
    User user;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {

        user = new User();
        user.setId(42L);
        user.setUsername("foobar");
        user.setFirstname("firstname");
        user.setLastname("lastname");
    }

    /**
     * Saving an object using the Cassandra Repository will create a persistent representation of the object in Cassandra.
     */
    @Test
    public void findSavedUserById() {

        user = repository.save(user);

        assertThat(repository.findOne(user.getId()), is(user));

    }

    /**
     * Cassandra can be queries by using query methods annotated with {@link @Query}.
     */
    @Test
    public void findByAnnotatedQueryMethod() {

        repository.save(user);

        assertThat(repository.findUserByIdIn(1000L), is(nullValue()));
        assertThat(repository.findUserByIdIn(42L), is(equalTo(user)));
    }

}
```

and everytime I tried to run Unit Test,
I always get these error messages:

```
20:02:16.672 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger] com.kashu.demo.UserRepositoryTest > findSavedUserById STARTED
20:02:16.867 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]
20:02:16.868 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger] com.kashu.demo.UserRepositoryTest > findSavedUserById FAILED
20:02:16.868 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]     java.lang.AssertionError: expected:<com.kashu.demo.User@554d7139> but was:<com.kashu.demo.User@6643364a>
20:02:16.869 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]         at org.junit.Assert.fail(Assert.java:88)
20:02:16.869 [QUIET] [system.out] 20:02:16.868 [
20:02:16.869 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]         at org.junit.Assert.failNotEquals(Assert.java:834) 
20:02:16.869 [QUIET] [system.out] INFO] [org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker] Gradle Test Executor 1 finished executing tests.
20:02:16.870 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]         at org.junit.Assert.assertEquals(Assert.java:118)
20:02:16.870 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]         at org.junit.Assert.assertEquals(Assert.java:144)
20:02:16.870 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]         at com.kashu.demo.UserRepositoryTest.findSavedUserById(UserRepositoryTest.java:67)
20:02:16.871 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
20:02:16.871 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
20:02:16.872 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]         at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
20:02:16.872 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
20:02:16.872 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]         at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
```

it seems like assertThat complaining 2 User objects to be compared are not equal, so should I do something in these code for successful test? if I need to compare equality between 2 objects, is the test code listed here a correct solution?

---

**[update]**

I add a equals() function in my User entity class, like this:

```
@Table(value = "users")
public class User {

    @PrimaryKey("user_id") private Long id;

    @Column("uname") private String username;
    @Column("fname") private String firstname;
    @Column("lname") private String lastname;

    public User(){

    }

    public User(Long id,String username,String firstname,String lastname) {
        this.id = id;
        this.username = username;
        this.firstname = firstname;
        this.lastname = lastname;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getFirstname() {
        return firstname;
    }

    public void setFirstname(String firstname) {
        this.firstname = firstname;
    }

    public String getLastname() {
        return lastname;
    }

    public void setLastname(String lastname) {
        this.lastname = lastname;
    }

    public boolean equals(Object obj){
        if (this==obj) return true;
        if (this.getClass() != obj.getClass()) return false;
        User user = (User) obj ;
           return (this.id == user.getId()) && 
                   (this.username.equals(user.getUsername())) &&
                   (this.firstname.equals(user.getFirstname())) && 
                   (this.lastname.equals(user.getLastname()));
    }



}
```

and tried to run unit test again , but I still got:

```
20:51:54.037 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger] com.kashu.demo.UserRepositoryTest > findSavedUserById STARTED
20:51:54.189 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]
20:51:54.189 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger] com.kashu.demo.UserRepositoryTest > findSavedUserById FAILED
20:51:54.189 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]     java.lang.AssertionError:
20:51:54.190 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]     Expected: is <com.kashu.demo.User@2fa98d0f>
20:51:54.190 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]          but: was <com.kashu.demo.User@44dab940>
20:51:54.190 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]         at org.hamcrest.MatcherAssert.assertThat(MatcherAssert.java:20)
```

any suggestions?

---

**[update2]**

I think maybe the logic I wrote into equals() function was wrong, so I tried fix my User's equals() function to this:

```
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    return true;
}
```

It looks very stupid but I can ensure what's going on, 
and after I done this and build my project again,
I saw message:
Gradle Test Run :test PASSED
so the problem is actually in equals() function
Ya , thank you everybody , You help me a lot!
sorry for my poor English skill :D

Comment: What does `User`'s `equals()` look like?

Comment: User's equals()  function leave completely blank ... is this the reason ?

Comment: Take a wild guess.

Comment: after you implement equals, do you still have error?

Comment: This question is a perfect example why one shouldn't rely on `equals` method for testing purposes. There are tools such as [shazamcrest](https://github.com/shazam/shazamcrest) that can help you with such problems.

Answer (score 0):

Any decent IDE can **generate** an equals method for your; based on the fields that you want to be used for an equals comparison. So, don't write up that stuff manually. Let the tool do the work for you.

Then: keep in mind that when overriding equals(), you should also override hashCode()!

Finally: what you did here is an example of "DDT" (see image below from [Geek&Poke](http://geek-and-poke.com/) for what I mean).

You shouldn't add an equals method to your production code because your tests are failing. Your tests should be failing if you **want** your code to have its own equals method! What I am saying is: don't add features to make tests pass (well, unless you wrote that test to remind you to implement a certain feature). Instead: decide which features you want in your product, and then write the tests accordingly.

And just for the fun of it: [image: DDT]